# Autosize webview into Container

Tags: flutter

In my project i need insert webview into Card---> Container----> Webview

Like this code above:

```
 Container(
                                                              height: MediaQuery.of(
                                                                          context)
                                                                      .copyWith()
                                                                      .size
                                                                      .height *
                                                                  0.4,
                                                              width: MediaQuery.of(
                                                                          context)
                                                                      .copyWith()
                                                                      .size
                                                                      .width *
                                                                  0.9,
                                                              child:
                                                                  WebView(
                                                                initialUrl: new Uri.dataFromString(
                                                                        '$html',
                                                                        mimeType:
                                                                            "text/html",
                                                                        encoding:
                                                                            Encoding.getByName('utf-8'))
                                                                    .toString(),
                                                                javascriptMode:
                                                                    JavascriptMode
                                                                        .unrestricted,
                                                              ))
```

But i need autoresize, because each webview content has a different styles and sizes.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
    return Container(
      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.4,
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.9,
      child: WebView(
          initialUrl: new Uri.dataFromString(
            '$html',
            mimeType: "text/html",
            encoding: Encoding.getByName('utf-8'),
          ).toString(),
          javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,),
    );
  }
}
```

this should do it

Answer (score -1):

Ok, i really found the solutions, Webiew doens't contain auto sized, you need input this into another widget and put height and widht.
But this package can resolve this: https://pub.dev/packages/social_embed_webview/example.

```
Container( padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
    child: SocialEmbed(socialMediaObj:TwitterEmbedData(embedHtml: htmlContent)),)
```

Now i can resize webview content.